What is the problem in this matlab code for Laplace Transform
I have been trying to visualize various Mathematical functions and have been using MATLAB for it. While writing code for this Laplace Transform of periodic function,
The function is;
f(t) = sin(w*t)        0 < t < pi/2

     = 0               pi/2 < t < 2*pi/w

The error that I get is
Error using symengine Unable to generate code for piecewise for use in anonymous functions.

Error in sym/matlabFunction>mup2mat (line 432) res1 = mupadmex('symobj::generateMATLAB',r.s,ano,spa);

Error in sym/matlabFunction>mup2matcell (line 401) r = mup2mat(c{1},true,sparseMat);

Error in sym/matlabFunction (line 172) body = mup2matcell(funs, opts.Sparse);

Error in Laplace_viz_2 (line 6) f_func = matlabFunction(f);

This is the code that I have used
syms t w s 
f = piecewise((0< t<pi/2), sin(w*t), (pi/2<t<2*pi/w), 0);
F = laplace (f, t , s);
pretty (F);

f_func = matlabFunction(f);
F_func = matlabFunction(F);

t_vals = linspace(0 , 3*pi/w , 500) ; 
s_vals = linspace (0, 100, 500);
w_vals = 2*pi/t ;

f_vals = arrayfunc(@t. f_func, t_vals) ;
F_vals = arrayfunc(@s, F_func, s_vals) ;

figure;
subplot(2, 1, 1);
plot(t_vals, f_vals, 'b', 'LineWidth', 2);
xlabel('t');
ylabel('f(t)');
title('Periodic Function');
grid on;

figure;
subplot(2, 1, 2);
plot(s_vals, F_vals, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
xlabel('s');
ylabel('F(s)');
title('Laplace of Periodic Function');
grid on;

For getting rid of those errors i have tried to use logics instead of piecewise function but still it returned errors.
I want to be able to get the graph of original function and also the graph of Laplace Transform Function.

Why not use fplot? https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fplot.html

Also, 0< t<pi/2 is not valid MATLAB syntax, you need to write (0<t) & (t<pi/2). What is your function’s value at t==pi/2?
